# 2Pb+O2+2H2SO4=2PbSO4+2H2O how many electrons are transferred in this process?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

How many electrons are transferred in the process of this REDOX reaction? What would be all the oxidation numbers assigned to all the species in this equation?

Comment: Review the guides [Asking](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) and [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Not following the guidance may lead to lack of satisfying answers, objections, question down-voting or even question closure.  
//  Note that questions, looking like copied  homework/test/exam/lab tasks without significant explicit resolving attempts, are explicitly off-topic on this site and will be closed.

Comment: Why won't you assign the said oxidation numbers and see what they are?

Comment: Isn't that similar to a [lead/acid battery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery)?  Read on.

Answer (score 1):

The reaction is cited as follows:

$\ce{2Pb(s) + O2(g) + 2H2SO4 (aq) -> 2 PbSO4(s) + 2H2O}$

$\ce{2 Pb -> 2 Pb++ + 4e-}$

$\ce{4 H+ + 4e- + O2 -> 2H2O}$

SO4 does not react.  4 electrons are transferred.

Oxidation number of S in SO4 is +6, the 4 Os are -2 each. H is +1, Lead Pb goes from 0 to +2.  Oxygen in O2 goes from 0 to -2.

Further checking has yielded this possibility:

$\ce{Pb(s) + PbO2(s) + 2H2SO4 (aq) -> 2PbSO4 (s) + 2 H2O}$

... what powers a [lead/acid battery](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery) cell, **+ 2.05 V**.

The charges on PbO2 are +4 for lead and -2 for the oxygens.  The number of electrons transferred is the same, 4.

Comment: Interestingly, one *could* say only 2 electrons are transferred from Pb 0 to Pb+4 -> 2 Pb+2, because oxygen has already "taken" 4 electrons from Pb.